# A Solution to Kubernetes pods stuck on Terminating

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04

I was one that was having trouble with this above mentioned issue where after a "kubectl delete -f" my container would be stuck on "Terminating".
I could not see anything in the Docker logs to help me narrow it down.
After a Docker restart the pod would be gone and i could continue as usual, but this is not the way to live your life.

I Googled for hours and finally got something on a random post somewhere.

Solution:
When i installed Kubernetes on Ubuntu 16.04 i followed a guide that said to install "docker.io".
In this article it said to remove "docker.io" and rather use a "docker-ce or docker-ee" installation.

BOOM, i did it, disabled the swappoff function and my troubles are no more.

I hope this helps people that are also stuck with this.

Cheers

Comment: can you share kubectl logs  as described https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer to this question?

Comment: Well, when i checked kubectl logs -f <pod>, it did not give me anything, 
My solution was to do the following:

*sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker-ce docker.io
*sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io -y
*curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
*sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable" 
*sudo apt-get update
*sudo apt-get install docker-ce -y
*sudo service docker restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [kleuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8019337/kleuf) mentioned in comments, the solution to the stuck docker container in his case was the following:

> When i installed Kubernetes on Ubuntu 16.04 i followed a guide that
>   said to install "docker.io". In this article it said to remove
>   "docker.io" and rather use a "docker-ce or docker-ee" installation.

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker-ce docker.io 
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io -y 
curl -fsSL download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo add-apt-repository  "deb [arch=amd64] download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu  $(lsb_release -cs)  stable" 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install docker-ce -y 
sudo service docker restart
```

> BOOM, i did it, disabled the swappoff function and my troubles are no
>   more.
>
> I hope this helps people that are also stuck with this.